# How to send messages between components through a service

Tags: angular

I have these two components: ping and pong, Ping should send a message to pong through a service. By the use of Rxjs but nothing seems to me send or received though am using the official documentation example. 
Here is the code of the service and the two components:

Service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagingServiceService {
  private _message : Subject<string>  = new Subject<string>();
  message$ : Observable<string>;
  constructor() { 
    this.message$ = this._message.asObservable();
  }

  sendMessage(message: string)
  {
    console.log(this.message$);
    this._message.next(message);
  }
}
```

Ping component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessagingServiceService } from '../messaging-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ping',
  templateUrl: './ping.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ping.component.css']
})
export class PingComponent implements OnInit {

  message :string = "";
  constructor(private messageService : MessagingServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendMessage()
  {
    console.log(this.message);
    this.messageService.sendMessage(this.message);
  }

}
```

Pong component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessagingServiceService } from '../messaging-service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pong',
  templateUrl: './pong.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pong.component.css']
})
export class PongComponent implements OnInit {

  recivedMessage :string ="";
  constructor(private messagingService: MessagingServiceService) {
    this.reciveMessages();
    this.messagingService.message$.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.recivedMessage = res;
    })

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  reciveMessages()
  {
    this.messagingService.message$.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.recivedMessage = res;
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: can you make a stackblitz?

Comment: because it works [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eutplz)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. just make sure your sendMessage method executed and your service is registered under providers in component module

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein isnt providedIn root enough ?

Comment: @Modz hussein you are right it's enough ..

Answer (score 0):

Change service like below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagingServiceService {
  private _message : Subject<string>  = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() { 
  }

  sendMessage(message: string)
  {
    this._message.next(message);
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this._message.asObservable();
  }
}
```

And please change your subsribe method as below.

```
import { Component, OnInit,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MessagingServiceService } from '../messaging-service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pong',
  templateUrl: './pong.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pong.component.css']
})
export class PongComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;

  recivedMessage :string ="";

  constructor(private messagingService: MessagingServiceService) {

   this.subscription = this.messagingService.getMessage().subscribe(res => {
      this.recivedMessage = res;
   });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```